# Add or push to Kendo grid datasource causes unexpected behaviour

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, datasource

I've got an array that, on its own, produces a grid no problem. I want to add one more row by pushing or adding to the datasource beforehand. Console.log after push shows the new array to be valid, but nothing appears on the Grid. Using add rather than push causes ONLY the new item to be display, while console.log shows all the items. Any ideas what gives?

EDIT: More strangely, I can loop through entries of a given array, extract some text and push that to a new array using ({'text':item[i].text}), but then outside of the loop pushing ({'text':'other text'}) doesn't show up as a row. Ugh.

EDIT #2: I've fixed the issue with the push to new array. Still not clear on certain kendoGrid functionality though, almost seems worth ignoring it altogether and just using kendoListView and utilising templates.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in http://dojo.telerik.com ?

Comment: I've fixed the push to new array because the variable was being overwritten. Still not sure why original method was producing unexpected behaviour. Oh well, hacking is as hacking does

Comment: So you've fixed it ?

Comment: As with a lot of things, I've found a way around it. Still don't understand some inconsistent Grid behaviour, though. Kind of wondering if others share my sentiment that there are simpler ways to perform the same kind of functionality. I'm reluctant because I'd have to rebuild quite a lot.

Comment: In my first months using kendo I have to use some work arounds to achieve some behaviours that now, with more some years into it, I know how it should be done. Somethings in this lib as obscure or hid in some deep documentation, unfortunatelly. Sharing your code is the only way to get the right support and help on your issue, tho.

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help. Maybe I'll get there over time, but for now I'm learning everything all at once, not just Kendo :) As far sharing code, it's almost like I don't have time to spend pulling out the useful/relevant bit of code AND figuring out how to format it for this site - I'm such a noob that even posting stuff on stack overflow causes me problems :D

Comment: I see. It is very simple, tho. You just paste your relevant code part into the text area, select it and press the *Code Sample* button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdvHJ.png Doesn't matters if it is out of format, someone will do it for you, until you get practice on it.

Comment: Thanks. I've got another question on another aspect of Kendo and I suppose Javascript functions in general. Would you mind if I PM you...if I can figure out/find where to do that in amongst all these chaotically placed random buttons and options?

Comment: I would prefer if you post another question and link it here for me, rather than that. Can you do it ? I will be glad to help.

Comment: Sorry, got side-tracked by other bits of code. I have a kendoDropDownList with a select function defining actions depending on option selected. This dropDownList is copy pasted to different to different parts of the dom because it's slower to keep re-creating it.  But, I'm not able to figure out how to pass additional variables to it based on where it currently is. I mean, if I access e.dataItem then all that exists is what was there when the dropDownList was created. Variations of `$("#dropdown").data('kendoDropDownList').some_method' haven't worked so far, but I suspect the answer lies here.

Comment: How do you *copy pasted* it to other places in DOM ? I have an idea of how achieve that.

Comment: Sorry, I used 'non-programming' language to describe the process of appending the wrapper for the dropDownList to another part of the dom :)

Comment: So you create just one widget and like copy it(e.g. [`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)) to somewhere else ?

Comment: That's right, with append() and updating the coordinates of the wrapper that has position:absolute. I want to pass the coordinates into the select: funtion. 
 Also, I'd like to switch between 2 dataSources at the new place where the dropDown is appended. I'm looking now if filtering works for dataSources...

Comment: OR, would an alternative (but still quick) option be to append a new dataSource at the new location. I can include the options I want AND the additional variables?

Comment: Well, I would suggest you to use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)(e.g. `data-ddl-name="dropdown1"` in the widget main element) for each new dropdown you create. Then, inside any event or function, you can always do `$(this.element).data("ddl-name")`(where `this` is the widget instance) to know which widget it works for. I can't get a big picture of what you're doing with all that DOM manipulation actually, but I think this might work.

Comment: Great! I've only recently begun to understand and use data attributes. In this case I've actually gone with another solution that's better for UX, but the knowledge will no doubt come in handy. Thanks again!

Comment: It's for HTML canvas stuff :)

Comment: Ok, glad to help mate.